# Convert Times To String and Add To Txt In C

Tags: c, string, function, time, time-series

I Have a problem, I have function saveDatabase to add and send data to txt, savaDatabase have 7 parameters, but I have problem with date and time parameters, but I'll show you 1 example for this,

int time parameter will get a data from timeSystem function. timeSystem will get a local time from the device and then return the value of it, but when I did that the time parameters will return the random numbers.

For example when i run the program with my codes below, I expected the result in txt file like this :

5, ***15/11/21*** , 12, 13 , 5000, *result from ticketDiscount function* , *result from ticketCounter*

But when I check the txt file, I get something like this :
5, ***56*** , 12, 13 , 5000, *result from ticketDiscount function* , *result from ticketCounter*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>

void saveDatabase();
int timeSystem();

int main(void)
{

   saveDatabase( 5, timeSystem(), 12, 13, 50000, ticketDiscount(1, 2), ticketCounter(5, 3) );

}

int timeSystem(){
    char line[500] = "\xb3";
    char dateCatch[100];
    time_t currentTime;
    time(&currentTime);
    struct tm *myTime = localtime(&currentTime);
    return ("%02i:%02i:%02i", myTime->tm_hour, myTime->tm_min, myTime->tm_sec);
}

void saveDatabase( int date, int time, int ticketRegular, int ticketVip, int totalPrices, int discount, int totalPayment ){
    FILE *database;

    if ((database = fopen("./database.txt", "a")) == NULL)
        {
            // Useless
            printf("ERROR 505 -- DATABASE FILE NOT FOUND -- ");
            printf("Please Contact Our Manager");
            exit(1);
        } 
    
    fprintf(database, "\xb3 Date : %d | Time : %i | Regular : %d | VIP : %d | Prices : %d | Discount : %d | Payment : %d \xb3\n", date, time, ticketRegular, ticketVip, totalPrices, discount, totalPayment);
    fclose(database);
    
}
```

Should I convert the time to string or what? any ideas? Thankyou

Comment: The `return` statement in `timeSystem` doesn't return what you think it returns. It seems like you're looking for something liek [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime).

Comment: On an unrelated note, when declaring function remember to include the arguments in the declaration. Otherwise the compiler will not be able to tell you if you use wrong types of arguments when calling it. And in fact, you could pass the completely wrong arguments leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Okay Thankyou, I'll Try it!